# If $L(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is the space of $\Bbb{R}$-linear maps from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$, which of the following are true?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is from an exam question:

> Let $L(\Bbb{R}^n)$ be the space of $\Bbb{R}$-linear maps from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$. If $\ker(T)$ denotes the kernel (null space) of $T$ then which of the following are true?:
>
> 1. There exists $T\in L(\Bbb{R}^5)\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\DeclareMathOperator{range}{range}\range(T)=\ker(T)$.
> 2. There does not exist $T\in L(\Bbb{R}^5)\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\DeclareMathOperator{range}{range}\range(T)=\ker(T)$.
> 3. There exists $T\in L(\Bbb{R}^6)\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\DeclareMathOperator{range}{range}\range(T)=\ker(T)$.
> 4. There does not exist $T\in L(\Bbb{R}^6)\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\DeclareMathOperator{range}{range}\range(T)=\ker(T)$.
>
> [(Image that replaced text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YIJo.jpg)

My attempt: by using rank nullity theorem I got options $2,3$.

Is it correct?

Notes: some of my friends say me that this question is wrong... so I'm very confused now why this question is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(3) is certainly true (hence (4) is false). For example, you can take a transformation $T$ whose matrix representation (in whatever basis you like) is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

It is correct that (2) is true (hence (1) is false). Indeed, (2) would be true if $\Bbb R^5$ were replaced by $\Bbb R^{2k+1}$ for any nonnegative integer $k$. Can you see why?

Comment: Not all such linear map T will  satisfy  $Ker T = Range T$

Comment: @Messififa I can't figure out what your point is. "Not all such linear map...": _what_ linear maps are you referring to here? There's only one linear map in the post you're commenting on, and it _does_ have range = kernel.

Answer (score 1):

*Note-* $T:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ can be viewed as an $n×n$ matrix such that *Rank-nullity formula*

$rank(T)+null(T)=n$

must hold in any case. This rejects option 1 and 4.